# Tweepy : How to get user id who liked(fav) the specified tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I wonder how to get user-id list who liked the specified tweet id.

I can see the number of favorites of the tweet by using 'favorite count', but would like to know WHO liked the tweet.

The same question as
[Twitter API - Getting list of users who favorited a status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982850/twitter-api-getting-list-of-users-who-favorited-a-status)
, which was written in python2, so I re-write in python3.
However it seems it does not work any longer.

```
def get_user_ids_who_likes(post_id):
    try:
        url = 'https://twitter.com/i/activity/favorited_popup?id=' + str(post_id)
        json_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
        found_ids = re.findall(r'data-user-id=\\"+\d+', json_data.decode('utf-8'))
        unique_ids = list(set([re.findall(r'\d+', match)[0] for match in found_ids]))
        return unique_ids
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        return False
```

Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`tweepy.Client.get_liking_users()`](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.4.0/client.html#tweepy.Client.get_liking_users).

---

> ```
> Client.get_liking_users(id, *, expansions, media_fields, place_fields, poll_fields, tweet_fields, user_fields)
> ```
>
> Allows you to get information about a Tweet’s liking users.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - `id (Union[int, str])` – Tweet ID of the Tweet to request liking users of.
> - `expansions (Union[List[str], str])` – [expansions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/expansions)
> - `media_fields (Union[List[str], str])` – [media_fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/media)
> - `place_fields (Union[List[str], str])` – [place_fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/place)
> - `poll_fields (Union[List[str], str])` – [poll_fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/poll)
> - `tweet_fields (Union[List[str], str])` – [tweet_fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet)
> - `user_fields (Union[List[str], str])` – [user_fields](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/user)
>
> #### Returns:
>
> Return type
> `Union[dict, requests.Response, Response]`
>
> #### References:
>
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/api-reference/get-tweets-id-liking_users

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I wanted!