# Tweepy: Getting the Account's of users who liked or retweeted a Tweet

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to write a function that can succesfully create a List of all (or some) accounts who have liked a Tweet. To achieve this I have used Tweepys get_liking_users function. I have previously succesfully requested the Tweet Infos of some Tweets and am now using the Tweet ID of a Tweet I know for certain has been both liked and rewteeted (I checked it on Twitter).

This is my code:

```
def findLikers():
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='XXX')

    id = 'XXX'

    users = client.get_liking_users(id=id, max_results=10)

    print(type(users))
    print(users)
```

However, when running this I get an empty response as exemplified by my print statements.
This is the Output:

```
<class 'tweepy.client.Response'>
Response(data=None, includes={}, errors=[], meta={'result_count': 0})
```

I'm pretty certain that the Tweet ID is correct, I looked it up on Twitter to ensure it is the tweet I mean (and actually has likes and retweets) and ran a seperate request to return the Tweet Text for the ID, which worked. However when running `get_liking_users()` or `get_retweers()` it consistently returns data=None, even though as I said, according to the UI there are both likes and retweets.

I tried to follow the tutorial here: https://dev.to/twitterdev/a-comprehensive-guide-for-using-the-twitter-api-v2-using-tweepy-in-python-15d9; and also saw this: [Tweepy : How to get user id who liked(fav) the specified tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126700/tweepy-how-to-get-user-id-who-likedfav-the-specified-tweet), however I was unable to fix the problem.

(As the functions ittself are pretty new, I think Twitter introduced an endpoint for this in May 2021, I could not find a lot of material on them except the Stackoverflow post above)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

(If there's any more Information I can provide, I'd be happy to, this is my first time asking something here)

I tried running the tweepy get_liking_users function and also tried the same steps with the get_retweeters function. I was hoping, the request would return the User ID's of all Twitter accounts that had liked/retweeted the Tweet. However The data is always None. I tried using some other ID's of some other Tweets, however the result stayed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta `resoult_count` 0 means, your tested tweet ID no liked people.

I demo one of tweet from `Nike` with your looking users who liked Tweet by API and `Tweepty`.

`Nike` -> user id

`1582388225049780230` -> tweet id

```
https://twitter.com/Nike/status/1582388225049780230
```

[image]

#### API

#1 liked user for tweet

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1582388225049780230/liking_users
```

[image]

[image]

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1582388225049780230/?tweet.fields=public_metrics&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=public_metrics
```

We can get the numbers for `retweet number` and `liked number`
[image]

#### Get Tweet liked user list by tweepy

```
import tweepy

bearer_token ="*************************"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

tweet_id="1582388225049780230"
users = client.get_liking_users(id=tweet_id, max_results=5)

print(type(users))          # <class 'tweepy.client.Response'>
print(type(users.data))     # <class 'list'>
print(type(users.data[0]))  # <class 'tweepy.user.User'>

for user in users.data:
    print(user.name, " -> ",user.id,",",user.username)

    # jose rojas say  ->  1610877195710304256 , rojassay1
    # Ochy Ras  ->  1400520916795281409 , GirimbaMweusi
    # Tapiwanashe Kandoje  ->  1497970355872452612 , TapiwanasheKan
```

You can see matched liked users (last 3 people) as previous screen image.

The returned users type is `tweepy.client.Response`
You can see tweepy's API

```
https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#likes
```

[image]

If click last red box, will go API likes

```
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/likes/api-reference/get-tweets-id-liking_users
```

[image]

if scroll down, you can see example of response

the `data` and it's child array item are `id`, `name` and `username`
**That WHY my for loop print those variables.**

[image]

#### Full code in here [get all of re tweeter user list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986120/how-does-the-api-get-retweeter-ids-actually-work-tweepy-python/75045630#75045630)

#### Get Re Tweet User list by `tweepy`

Same idea how to get type and how to print it as same as get liked user list.

```
import tweepy

bearer_token ="*************************"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=bearer_token)

tweet_id="1582388225049780230"
retweeters = client.get_retweeters(id=tweet_id, max_results=3)

print(type(retweeters))          # <class 'tweepy.client.Response'>
print(type(retweeters.data))     # <class 'list'>
print(type(retweeters.data[0]))  # <class 'tweepy.user.User'>

for retweeter in retweeters.data:
    print(retweeter.name, " -> ",retweeter.id,",",retweeter.username)

    # valmig  ->  1594136795905593344 , AngelVa00615402
    # Wyatt Jones  ->  764734669434871808 , TheGhostZeus
    # Prime Projects  ->  1603887705242435584 , PrimeProjects4
```

It will matched retweet user's list from UI.
[image]

Comment: Hey there, thank you so much for your answer!
After reading through your answer and code, I looked at mine again and tried it with the ID from your post, and it worked! I just had to slightly edit the print to use `user.name.encode("utf-8")` because without that I kept getting the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I also tried some of the Tweet ID's I had before with the reworked code and realized why they returned None: They did have likes and retweets but the posts themselves were just retweets, I think that's why I got None as a result so often.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: you are welcome, I am happy to hear you got it.